# How can i print multiple query output in GLOBAL:PHP view field?

Tags: views

I have custom global:php fields on which I put the following code as value.

```
$shop_url=db_query("select page_url from mytable1 where user_id=$row->uid");
return $shop_url;
```

As output code, I put the following one.

```
foreach($shop_url as $data) {
  print($data->page_url);
}
```

I am getting no output. How can I achieve printing multiple database results in GLOBAL:PHP?

Answer (score 2):

There are many errors in your code :)

First, **don't use $data variable**, as it's already used in your view ; check the *available variables* section under your php inputs. Normally, it's advised to use **$static**.

Second, did you check elsewhere that

`$shop_url=db_query("select page_url from mytable1 where user_id=$row->uid");`

returns something ? Because I would have thought that only

`$shop_url=db_query("select page_url from mytable1 where user_id=:uid", array(':uid' => $row->uid));`

would work.

Comment: What is the difference between doing `print($something); and print $something;`? My guess would be none.

Comment: You're totally right. print is not actually a real function (it is a language construct) so you are not required to use parentheses with its argument list.